# Can I work in Singapore without cancelling the Malaysia EP

Tags: singapore, malaysia, visa-cancellation, work-permit

I have got an offer from Singapore and the EP approval, but the agency in Malaysia is asking me to pay an extra two months except for the notice period. So Can I leave Malaysia employment without cancelling the EP and start work in Singapore without any issue. because I don't have much money to pay to the Malaysian Agency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, Singapore does not care whether you have work permits in other countries.

Some caveats:

- You are still responsible for Malaysian tax clearance, returning your Malaysia ID cards, etc, and may need to return to Malaysia to complete this.
- I'm not sure what your contract says, but the agency trying to impose fees on you will likely find it difficult to collect them even in Malaysia, much less Singapore.  If the fees are not mentioned in your contract at all, you can tell them to go pound sand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind advice.